# Why Deprecation Warning and ValueError shows up even when the shapes and length of input arrays is same?

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, sklearn-pandas

I am partitioning my data using `train_test_split`. I have got 2 features to fit, namely 'horsepower' and 'price' of the car each containing 199 elements. So I tried out the following code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    lm=LinearRegression()

    x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test =train_test_split(df['horsepower'],df['price'],test_size=0.3,random_state=0)

    model = lm.fit(x_train, y_train)
    predictions = lm.predict(x_test)

    #Now, just to recheck:
    print(x_train.shape == y_train.shape)
    >>>True

    #And
    len(x_train)
    >>>139

    len(y_train)
    >>>139
```

However all I am getting is a `DeprecationWarning` and `ValueError`:

> DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17
>   and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using
>   X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1)
>   if it contains a single sample.

and

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 139]

Comment: It is all about orientation - which dimension for rows and which for columns. I guess you may use `df[['horsepower']]` to make it right or use `reshape` as warning suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sklearn requires your X data shape as `(n_row, n_column)`.

When you select a column in `DataFrame` by `df['horsepower']`, what you get is a `pandas.Series`, and thus your shape is `(n_row,)`.

To avoid this, you have two options:

- select your column in this way: `df[['horsepower']]`, this gives you a new `DataFrame` and thus the shape is `(n_row, n_column)`
- do `reshape` before fitting your model: `x_train = x_train.reshape(-1,1)` and `x_test = x_test.reshape(-1,1)`